# Highlight current page/content type in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Im creating a menu from a custom post type "service" and I want to highlight the page I'm on. How do I do that?

Everything works in the code below (below this code) except this part that I need help for:

```
if ( current_page_on == this_menu_item_from_loop ) {
    // This is the current page - highlight the <li>
}
```

...

```
<?php
$type = 'services';
$args=array('post_type' => $type);

$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        if ( current_page_on == this_menu_item_from_loop ) {
            // This is the current page - highlight the <li>
        }
    ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
    <?php
  endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself :)

```
<?php
    $page_ID = get_the_ID();

    $type = 'services';
    $args=array(
      'post_type' => $type);

    $my_query = null;
    $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
    if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
            if ( get_the_ID() == $page_ID ) {
                $current = ' class="current"';
            }
        ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"<?php echo $current; ?>><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php
            $current = '';
      endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```